# Azure shut down schedule

Tags: azure, configuration, microsoft-dynamics, azure-virtual-machine

We have a client who runs Dynamics NAV infrastructure on Azure VM. I am about to configure a schedule in such a way,it matches office hours. 
What will happen if service is used at shutdown time and other user interacting with the service running on VM. Is there a way to manage that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am about to configure a schedule in such a way,it matches office
>   hours.

You could use Azure runbook to schedule start or stop your VM, please refer to this [blog](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axology/archive/2016/12/09/automated-startup-and-shutdown-of-azure-vms).

> What will happen if service is used at shutdown time and other user
>   interacting with the service running on VM.

If your VM shutdown, Dynamics NAV could not provide service. If your user need Dynamics NAS service, you need start your VM.

Comment: I read that already,probably question is ambiguous, sorry, what I meant is: what will happen if shutdown is scheduled for 6pm, but there is still a user using it. Will it perform shutdown? Is there a way to control that behaviour?

Comment: @ArturAkhmetgareev It will shutdown even some user still use it. `Is there a way to control that behaviour?` No, in VM, you could not cancel shutdown, but you could notification before shutdown.

Comment: @ArturAkhmetgareev If you don't ensure if users use it at 6pm. I suggest you could delayed shutdown, such as 7pm.